# Repeated Multiplication formula for Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I am looking for a way to get excel to multiply a formula by ANOTHER 3 after each consecutive calculation.

Basically, I have a column with numbers in `A: 10; 20; 30; 40 ...`

And what I'm looking for is in `B1 = (10 mult 3) = 30; in B2 = (20 mult 3 mult 3) = 180; in B3 = (30 mult 3 mult 3 mult 3) = 810 ...`

Thanks for any tips and help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun little problem using some basic maths:

```
=A1*3^ROW(A1)
```

[image]

Kept it simple, but there is the power() function that could be used.
Do take care if you start in a row other than 1...

Comment: You are an absolute miracle! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it works then accept the answer with the check mark. Thanks.